# How to edit a json payload with set-body in azure api management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I want to edit an outbound payload using set-body in this way:

{"link": "http://localhost:7071/api"}
to
{"link":""} <- some other link

I have tried this but there is no change in outbound:

```
JObject inBody = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>(); 
string str = inBody.ToString();
var item = JObject.Parse("{ 'link': 'http://localhost:7071/api}");
item["link"] = "https://randomlink/269";
return str;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain why your code does not work:

```
JObject inBody = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>(); //Request
payload has been parsed and stored in `inBody` variable.
string str = inBody.ToString(); //`inBody` converted to string and stored in `str` variable.
var item = JObject.Parse("{ 'link': 'http://localhost:7071/api}"); //Some other JSON parsed and stored in `item` variable
item["link"] = "https://randomlink/269"; //`item` variable updated with new value
return str; //Returning `str` variable as new body value
```

You never actually change value of `str` to produce new body. Try:

```
JObject inBody = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>(); 
inBody["link"] = "https://randomlink/269";
return inBody.ToString();
```