# Is there any way to fetch a Json file in Azure Blob Storage at APIM and forward to Backend as a json payload?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I am looking for a way to fetch a JSON file in Azure Blob storage at APIM layer, make it a part of the payload then forward it to the Backend engine (Function App). Appreciate it if you guys can share a sample C# snippet with me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the send request policy to fetch the blob

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-send-request#send-request

and then use the policy expression to append it to your requests

[How to edit a json payload with set-body in azure api management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69249932/how-to-edit-a-json-payload-with-set-body-in-azure-api-management)